# Histogram on SSRS reporting

Tags: sql, reporting-services, histogram

I have data from a query and would like to chart it on SSRS. I cannot find the **histogram** option where I can specify the interval and bucket size. I can run the query and specify the bucket sizes in the sql query, but I would like to have it variable.

Online it says to create a column chart then go to the **CustomAttribute** section of the data series and select '**Show column as'**, I however do not find the option **CustomAttribute** and **'ShowColumnAs'** option.

Can someone please assist with letting me know how to create a histogram in SSRS and where to access the options to create it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access these properties using the properties panel, I don;t think they are available from the UI properties popup.

Click on the series in the chart, then hit F4. It's F4 in visual studio, in Report Builder I'm not sure if F4 works, you may have to switch the properties panel on.

[image]

Then expand the Custom Attributes group and you'll see the properties you need.